# Are there any examples of closed form solutions of transcendental equations

Tags: transcendental-equations

An ambitious and amateur question regarding closed form solution of equations involving finite exponential terms.

Comment: Does this count: $e^{x}=1$ only has solution $x=0$ (or $x=2\pi ik$ if you count complex number). I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you mean some $z\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n e^{b_n z}=0$ ? If the $a_n,b_n$ are any kind of complex numbers then given $z$ we can always choose $a_N$ such that ... thus you'd need additional constraints to make the problem interesting.

Comment: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) which has several examples.